# On delete restrict SQL help

Tags: sql, db2, restrict, alter

I have the two following tables:

```
    Owner:

    O_ID P_ID
    Bob   Sam
    Steve Rex


    Pets

    P_ID O_ID
    Sam  Bob
    Rex  Steve
```

The second column of owners (P_ID) is a foreign key to the first column of pets (P_ID).

In DB2, I'm trying to add an ON_DELETE RESTRICT constraint, such that if someone were to try and delete an Owner in the owner table, if that owner were the owner of a pet, the delete operation would be rejected. I know I have to use the ON_DELETE RESTRICT command, but I'm at a loss of how to do so.

I've tried this:

```
ALTER TABLE OWNERS
ADD CONSTRAINT no_delete
FOREIGN KEY (P_ID)
REFERENCES PETS(P_ID)
ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

To no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax is correct. Your logic is wrong.

You want to prevent deleting an owner if it has a pet in the table "pets". To do that, you need to alter the table "pets", and add a foreign key constraint referencing the table "owners".

Comment: I already have such a constraint in place - at least I'm pretty sure I do.

Comment: @Waffles: You can check with the `db2look` utility.

Answer (score 3):

Catcall is correct, here's the correct ALTER TABLE  command (tested in DB2 LUW v9.7):

> ALTER TABLE pets ADD CONSTRAINT
>   no_delete FOREIGN KEY (P_ID)
>   REFERENCES owner(P_ID) ON DELETE
>   RESTRICT;

Then when I tried to remove Steve from the owner table with the following command:

> DELETE FROM owner where O_ID =
>   'Steve';

I received, as expected:

> DB21034E  The command was processed as
>   an SQL statement because it was not a
>   valid Command Line Processor command. 
>   During SQL processing it returned:
>   SQL0532N  A parent row cannot be
>   deleted because the relationship
>   "DB2INST1.PETS.NO_DELETE" restricts
>   the deletion.  SQLSTATE=23001

Then to make sure this is working completely as expected, I erased Steve's dog:

> DELETE FROM pets WHERE O_ID = 'Steve'

And re-ran the attempt to remove Steve from the owner table, and it worked!